# Diagrams in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, diagrams

MV VS 2005 had such project types like "Application Diagram", "Logical Datacenter Diagram", "System Diagram".

Are there any similar project types in VS2008/2010?

What I need is to have ability to draw some picture (diagram) of my applications, how they are communicating to each other (using web services), etc.

Thanks.

P.S. If it is possible for "Professional" version (not for Ultimate).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a head start:

http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Good, but for ultimate version only... :(